# How can I get rid of lag and optimize my Android game?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-cs5

I just finished up building my Android Game with flash cs5. I added Admob ads and I noticed that in-game play the game would "jump" or jitter whenever the ad moves or changes. Is there any way I could optimize my code so I can make it less laggy and jittery? Here's a sample of my In-Game code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.display.MovieClip;


var STATE_INIT_GAME:String = "STATE_INIT_GAME";
var STATE_PLAY_GAME:String = "STATE_PLAY_GAME";
var STATE_END_GAME:String = "STATE_END_GAME";
var gameState:String;
var hearts:Array;
var atoms:Array;
var bombs:Array;
var enemies:Array;
var level:Number;
var score:Number;
var lives:Number;
var tempHeart:MovieClip;
var tempBomb:MovieClip;
var tempAtom:MovieClip;
var tempEnemy:MovieClip;
var rSound:rMusic = new rMusic  ;
var Rchannel:SoundChannel;
var offset:int = 23;
var enemyBaseSpeed:int = 4;
var speedLevelInc:Number = 3;
var MAX_SPEED:Number = 22;
score = 0;
var identityMatrix:Matrix=new Matrix()
roachLevel.score_txt.text = String(score);

function gameLoopR(e:Event):void
{
    switch (gameState)
    {
        case STATE_INIT_GAME :
            initGame();
            break;
        case STATE_PLAY_GAME :
            playGame();
            break;
        case STATE_END_GAME :
            endGame();
            break;
    }
}
function initGame():void
{

    Rchannel = rSound.play(0,9999);
    level = 1;
    roachLevel.level_txt.text = String(level);
    lives = 3;
    roachLevel.lives_txt.text = String(lives);
    hearts = new Array();
    bombs = new Array();
    atoms = new Array();
    enemies = new Array();
    gameState = STATE_PLAY_GAME;
}
function playGame():void
{

    makeEnemies();
    moveEnemies();
    makeHearts();
    moveHearts();
    makeBombs();
    moveBombs();
    makeAtoms();
    moveAtoms();
    testForEnd();
}
function makeBombs():void
{
    var chance:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6000);
    if (chance <=  +  level)
    {
        tempBomb = new Bomb();
        tempBomb.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 480);
        addChild(tempBomb)
        tempBomb.scaleX = 1.5;
        tempBomb.scaleY = 1.5;
        tempBomb.cacheAsBitmapMatrix=identityMatrix;
        bombs.push(tempBomb);
        tempBomb.speed = 5;
    }
}

function moveBombs():void
{
    var tempBomb:MovieClip;

    for (var h:int =bombs.length-1; h>=0; h--)
    {

        tempBomb = bombs[h];
        if (tempBomb.dead)
        {
            Rchannel.stop();
            lives = 0;
            roachLevel.level_txt.text = String(lives);
            bombs.splice(h,1);
        }
        else
        {
            tempBomb.rotation += (Math.round(Math.random()*.4));
            tempBomb.y +=  (Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*tempBomb.rotation))*tempBomb.speed;
            if (tempBomb.x < 10)
            {
                tempBomb.x = 14;
            }
            if (tempBomb.x > stage.stageWidth - offset)
            {
                tempBomb.x = stage.stageWidth - offset;
            }
            if (tempBomb.y > stage.stageHeight)
            {
                removeBomb(h);

            }
        }
    }
}
function makeEnemies():void
{
    var chance:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 150);
    if (chance <= level && enemies.length < 4)
    {
        tempEnemy = new Enemy();
        tempEnemy.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 480);
        addChild(tempEnemy);
        tempEnemy.scaleX = 1.5;
        tempEnemy.scaleY = 1.5;
        tempEnemy.cacheAsBitmapMatrix=identityMatrix;
        enemies.push(tempEnemy);

        tempEnemy.speed = enemyBaseSpeed + ((level - 1) * speedLevelInc);
        if (tempEnemy.speed > MAX_SPEED)
        {
            tempEnemy.speed = MAX_SPEED;

        }


    }

}

function moveEnemies():void
{
    var tempEnemy:MovieClip;


    for (var i:int =enemies.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        tempEnemy = enemies[i];
        if (tempEnemy.dead)
        {
            score++;
            score++;
            roachLevel.score_txt.text = String(score);
            enemies.splice(i,1);

        }
        else
        {

            tempEnemy.rotation += (Math.round(Math.random()*.4));
            tempEnemy.y +=  (Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*tempEnemy.rotation))*tempEnemy.speed;
            if (tempEnemy.x < 10)
            {
                tempEnemy.x = 14;
            }
            if (tempEnemy.x > stage.stageWidth - offset)
            {
                tempEnemy.x = stage.stageWidth - offset;
            }
            if (tempEnemy.y > stage.stageHeight)
            {
                removeEnemy(i);

                lives--;
                roachLevel.lives_txt.text = String(lives);
            }
        }
    }
}
function makeHearts():void
{
    var chance:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8000);
    if (chance <=  +  level)
    {
        tempHeart = new Heart();
        tempHeart.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 480);
        addChild(tempHeart);
        tempHeart.scaleX = 1.5;
        tempHeart.scaleY = 1.5;
        tempHeart.cacheAsBitmapMatrix=identityMatrix;       
        hearts.push(tempHeart);

        tempHeart.speed = enemyBaseSpeed + ((level - 1) * speedLevelInc);
    }
}
function moveHearts():void
{
    var tempHeart:MovieClip;

    for (var k:int =hearts.length-1; k>=0; k--)
    {

        tempHeart = hearts[k];
        if (tempHeart.dead)
        {
            lives++;
            roachLevel.lives_txt.text = String(lives);
            hearts.splice(k,1);
        }
        else
        {
            tempHeart.rotation += (Math.round(Math.random()*.4));
            tempHeart.y +=  (Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*tempHeart.rotation))*tempHeart.speed;
            if (tempHeart.x < 10)
            {
                tempHeart.x = 14;
            }
            if (tempHeart.x > stage.stageWidth - offset)
            {
                tempHeart.x = stage.stageWidth - offset;
            }
            if (tempHeart.y > stage.stageHeight)
            {
                removeHeart(k);
            }
        }
    }
}

function makeAtoms():void
{
    var chance:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7500);
    if (chance <=  +  level)
    {
        tempAtom = new Atom();
        tempAtom.x = Math.round(Math.random() * 480);
        addChild(tempAtom);
        tempAtom.scaleX = 1.5;
        tempAtom.scaleY = 1.5;
        tempAtom.cacheAsBitmapMatrix=identityMatrix;
        atoms.push(tempAtom);
        tempAtom.speed = enemyBaseSpeed + ((level - 1) * speedLevelInc);
    }
}


function moveAtoms():void
{
    var tempAtom:MovieClip;

    for (var c:int =atoms.length-1; c>=0; c--)
    {

        tempAtom = atoms[c];
        if (tempAtom.dead)
        {
            score++;
            score++;
            score++;
            score++;
            score++;
            roachLevel.score_txt.text = String(score);
            atoms.splice(c,1);
        }
        else
        {
            tempAtom.rotation += (Math.round(Math.random()*.4));
            tempAtom.y +=  (Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*tempAtom.rotation))*tempAtom.speed;
            if (tempAtom.x < 10)
            {
                tempAtom.x = 14;
            }
            if (tempAtom.x > stage.stageWidth - offset)
            {
                tempAtom.x = stage.stageWidth - offset;
            }
            if (tempAtom.y > stage.stageHeight)
            {
                removeAtom(c);

            }
        }
    }
}
function removeEnemy(id:int)
{

    removeChild(enemies[id]);
    enemies.splice(id,1);
}
function removeHeart(kd:int)
{

    removeChild(hearts[kd]);
    hearts.splice(kd,1);
}
function removeBomb(hd:int)
{

    removeChild(bombs[hd]);
    bombs.splice(hd,1);
}
function removeAtom(cd:int)
{

    removeChild(atoms[cd]);
    atoms.splice(cd,1);
}
function testForEnd():void
{
    if (score > level * 20)
    {
        level++;
        roachLevel.level_txt.text = String(level);
    }
    if (lives == 0)
    {
        gameState = STATE_END_GAME;
    }

}
function endGame():void
{
    removeGame();
    roachLevel.visible = false;
    endscreen_mc.visible = true;
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoopR);
    showresults();

}
function removeGame():void
{
    for (var i:int = enemies.length-1; i >=0; i--)
    {
        removeEnemy(i);
    }
    for (var h:int = bombs.length-1; h >=0; h--)
    {
        removeBomb(h);
    }
    for (var k:int = hearts.length-1; k >=0; k--)
    {
        removeHeart(k);
    }
    for (var c:int = atoms.length-1; c >=0; c--)
    {
        removeAtom(c);
    }
}
```

Here's another sample code telling what to do when each button is clicked and what to show:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
flash.media.SoundMixer

stage.quality = StageQuality.MEDIUM
startMenu.play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Clicked);
startMenu.help_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, HelpClick);
bugsMenu.roach_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, RClick);
bugsMenu.spider_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, SClick);
bugsMenu.ants_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, AClick);
bugsMenu.back_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, BClick);
bugsMenu.fly_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, FClick);
bugsMenu.visible = false;
roachLevel.visible = false;
extras_mc.visible = false;
endscreen_mc.visible = false;
endscreenA_mc.visible = false;
endscreenS_mc.visible = false;
endscreenF_mc.visible = false;
extras_mc.visible = false;
information.visible = false;
medals_mc.visible = false;
medals2_mc.visible = false;
help_mc.visible = false;
spiderLevel.visible = false;
AntLevel.visible = false;
flyLevel.visible = false;
Menu_mc.visible = false;
menuA_mc.visible = false;
menuS_mc.visible = false;
menuF_mc.visible = false;
var theme:Intro = new Intro;
var tchannel:SoundChannel;
tchannel = theme.play(0,9999);

function Clicked(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    bugsMenu.visible = true;
    startMenu.visible = false;
}

function HelpClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    startMenu.visible = false;
    help_mc.visible = true;
}
function BClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
startMenu.visible = true;
help_mc.visible = false;
}
function RClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    tchannel.stop();
    bugsMenu.visible = false;
    roachLevel.visible = true;
    roachLevel.gotoAndPlay(1);
    gameState = STATE_INIT_GAME;
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoopR);

}
function SClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    tchannel.stop();
    bugsMenu.visible = false;
    spiderLevel.visible = true;
    gameStateS = STATE_INIT_GAMES;
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoopS);
}
function AClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    tchannel.stop();
    bugsMenu.visible = false;
    AntLevel.visible = true;
    gameStateA = STATE_INIT_GAMEA;
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoopA);
}
function FClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    tchannel.stop();
    bugsMenu.visible = false;
    flyLevel.visible = true;
    gameStateF = STATE_INIT_GAMEF;
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoopF);
}
```

I've tried everything to make it more optimized, but I don't understand what else I should do, please help!

Answer (score 0):

First advice - don't post more than 30-40 lines of code. You need to isolate the problems source.

Second - use profiling tools. Adobe released a wonderful profiling tool called Scout, use it to see your game's performance, memory allocation, rendering processes etc.
In your case that will actually isolate the problems source since you'll see where your app spikes CPU, GPU, memory usage.
Link to Adobe Scout: http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/scout/

Third - read some articles about mobile game development. Looking at your code it's clear you haven't read even the basics.
For example - always try to pre calculate, pool/reuse objects, cache necessary graphics, but don't abuse memory. For example - Math.PI/180 from your code can be calculated once and stored in a variable, no need to calculate it every frame.

The basics: http://gaming.adobe.com - has a number of very nice articles.

Fourth, using frame scripting over OOP approach is professional suicide. Consider refactoring your code with OOP, the benefits are countless.

Your question doesn't have a very clear solution - you basically need to write better code and test it along the way.

Comment: In addition to this answer make sure you read the agreement on Play Store, as it states that ads should not be visible while playing. Instead move your ads to menus, and you'll get more performance too.